# Explain why $P(\{\# C^p(y)=\infty\})=P(\{\# C^p(0)=\infty\})$. (Percolation)

Tags: probability-theory, percolation

We're in $\mathbb{Z}^d$, and we have a collection $(X_e^p)_{e \in E}$ where $P(X_e^p=1)=p=1-P(X_e^p=0)$, i.e. the probability of an edge $e$ being open is $p$.

Let $C^p(y)$ is a random open cluster, i.e. the set of all points in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ which are connected to $y \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ through open edges.

Why do we have $P(\{\# C^p(y)=\infty\})=P(\{\# C^p(0)=\infty\})$?

The book I'm reading states that it's due to translation invariance of the lattice... but I have no idea what that is, why that happens, and my web searches came up empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I've edited this question since I have another doubt, highly related to this one, and there would be no point of repeating the description of the context.

The book defines $C^p(x)=\{y \in \mathbb{Z}^d: x\leftrightarrow_p y\}$, where $y\leftrightarrow_p x$ means there is a open path between $y$ and $x$. I think I understand this, but then the author proceeds to state $\#C^p(x)=\sum_{y \in \mathbb{Z}^d} \mathbf{1}_{\{x\leftrightarrow_p y\}}$, which I'm not sure how to interpret, since $x$ is given, and $y$ is the index of the sum. What is the function $\mathbf{1}_{\{x\leftrightarrow_p y\}}$?

The author doesn't even define the event space, the $\sigma$-algebra, nor define a measure in the generating set of the sigma algebra.

Comment: The distribution of $C^p(y)$ is the same as the distribution of $y+C^p(0)$ because $(X^p_{y+e})_e$ and $(X^p_e)_e$ are both i.i.d. Bernoulli with parameter $p$, hence the distribution of the size $C^p(y)$ is the same as the distribution of the size of $C^p(0)$, in particular the probability that $C^p(y)$ is infinite is  the same as the probability that $C^p(0)$ is infinite.

Comment: @Did thanks for the helpful comment. I've edited the question. If you could help me, I would appreciate it. ;)

Comment: As usual, $\mathbf 1_{x\leftrightarrow y}=1$ if $x\leftrightarrow y$ and $\mathbf 1_{x\leftrightarrow y}=0$ otherwise. "The author doesn't even define the event space, the σσ-algebra, nor define a measure in the generating set of the sigma algebra." All these are implicit, yes, and quite easy to make explicit if one wishes to (but one does not) since the randomness is reduced to each edge being open or closed hence $\Omega=\{0,1\}^E$ would fit.

Comment: @Did thanks for the helpful comment. ;)